# GetDiskFreeSpace function returns ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION

Tags: c, winapi

I have the following code, which should get a handle to an external drive and get a sector size.

```
HANDLE hRawDisk = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\F:",
                             GENERIC_READ,
                             FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                             NULL,
                             OPEN_EXISTING, 
                             FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, 
                             NULL);

if (hRawDisk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("CreateFile failed\r\n");
    PrintLastError();
    return -1;
}

DWORD sectorsPerCluster;
DWORD bytesPerSector;
DWORD numberOfFreeClusters;
DWORD totalNumberOfClusters;

if (!GetDiskFreeSpace(L"\\\\.\\F:", &sectorsPerCluster, &bytesPerSector,
    &numberOfFreeClusters, &totalNumberOfClusters))
{
    printf("GetDiskFreeSpace failed\r\n");
    PrintLastError();
    CloseHandle(hRawDisk);
    return -2;
}
```

I don't know why the function GetDiskFreeSpace returns ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION. Is it possible that it has something to do with access rights?

Using of function GetDiskFreeSpaceEx gives exactly the same results.

Comment: From the MSDN documentation, `a drive specification must have a trailing backslash (for example, "C:\")`.

Comment: Wow. I can't believe I've overlooked it. Thanks.

Comment: Your error handling code is bad, you must call GetLastError() *before* you do anything else.  That printf() is screwing up the error value since it also makes OS calls under the hood.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the MSDN documentation for the function `GetDiskFreeSpace`, about the first parameter (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364935(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The root directory of the disk for which information is to be
>   returned. If this parameter is NULL, the function uses the root of the
>   current disk. If this parameter is a UNC name, it must include a
>   trailing backslash (for example, "\MyServer\MyShare\"). **Furthermore,**
>   **a drive specification must have a trailing backslash (for example,**
>   **"C:\").** The calling application must have FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY access
>   rights for this directory.

So, for example, you'd call the function in the following way:

```
GetDiskFreeSpace(L"F:\\", &sectorsPerCluster, &bytesPerSector,
    &numberOfFreeClusters, &totalNumberOfClusters)
```

Answer (score 0):

sample:

```
    auto path = _T("C:\\");
    ULARGE_INTEGER FreeBytesAvailable = { 0 };
    ULARGE_INTEGER TotalNumberOfBytes={ 0 };
    ULARGE_INTEGER TotalNumberOfFreeBytes={ 0 };

    BOOL ok = GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(
        path,
        &FreeBytesAvailable,
        &TotalNumberOfBytes,
        &TotalNumberOfFreeBytes
        );

    if (ok)
    {
        unsigned long long freeAvail = FreeBytesAvailable.QuadPart;
        unsigned long long total = TotalNumberOfBytes.QuadPart;
        unsigned long long totalfree = TotalNumberOfFreeBytes.QuadPart;

        TRACE("\nfree for user: MB: %lld; Total for user: MB: %lld, Free total MB:%lld \n", freeAvail /1024/1024, total / 1024 / 1024, totalfree / 1024 / 1024);


/// if eventually using MFC:
    CString s;
    s.Format(_T("free for user: MB: %lld; Total for user: MB: %lld, Free total MB:%lld \n"), freeAvail / 1024 / 1024, total / 1024 / 1024, totalfree / 1024 / 1024);
```